# importing swipelistview error

Tags: android, listview, import, swipe

I'm trying to import the swipelistview library to use on my project but I'm getting the following error.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Mc6a.png

I used this guide to get everything set up.
https://modewagon.wordpress.com/2013/09/16/getting-started-with-swipelistview/

I'm not sure exactly what the problem is or how I can fix it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: the `R` can not be the problem, has another error message?

Comment: I missed one part which I hadn't noticed before:

"Error:Execution failed for task ':libraries:swipelistview:compileReleaseJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details."

Comment: you can post your build.gradle?

Comment: I'll post it in another answer because I'm not good at formatting the comments.

Answer (score 0):

This is the swipelistview build.gradle

```
buildscript {

    repositories {

        mavenCentral()

    }

    dependencies {

        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'

    }

}

apply plugin: 'android-library'

dependencies {

    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'

    compile files ('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')

}

android {

    compileSdkVersion 22

    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    sourceSets {

        main {

            manifest.srcFile 'src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'

            java.srcDirs = ['src']

            res.srcDirs = ['res']

        }

    }

}
```

and this is the one in my app folder:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sda_app.sda"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile project(':libraries:swipelistview')
}
```